# LINE BOT - Private reply to a comment

Tags: bots, line.me

I'm replicating a messenger bot on the LINE platform. I need to respond to a comment privately, like on Facebook (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.12/object/private_replies). Is this possible on the Line platform? How?

(I did not find it in Line's documentation and that's why I turn it over here.)

Answer (score 0):

It's seems you want to send private message depend what message you get from user ?

You can get user identifier from webhook response and you can send direct message by using it

Comment: I want to respond privately to a comment that the user makes in any of the posts on my bot's page.